# How to present specific view controller when a cell is selected on iOS 6?

Tags: xcode, ios6

I am using Xcode 4.5.2, and iOS6.

I have 3 View Controllers, `FirstViewController` contains dynamic table view.
 What I want is, when the first row is selected it takes the user to `SecondViewController`, and when the second row is selected to the `ThirdViewController`.

Below is the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method of my code

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

NSIndexPath *path = indexPath;
NSInteger theInteger = path.row;


switch (theInteger)
{
    case 0:

        //here i wanna present FirstViewController

        break;
    case 1:
        //here i wanna present SecondViewController

        break;

    default:
        break;
  }
}
```

I am not sure if this is the best practice but this is all what I know. I hope I made it clear.

Comment: Are you using storyboard?

Comment: Yes, and I subclass each view controller